# Reload gridview in C# after searching something on textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

So i have a gridview showing some orders from my database and i would like to refresh my gridview after someone searches an order in a textbox i have to search but i cant do it as i am doing it right know because i already have a gridview loaded.

CS

```
public void refreshdata()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [Encomenda]", con);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

         protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [encomenda] where No_= @No_", con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_", txtSearch.Value);


        cmd.ExecuteReader();

            SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda1.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();

        con.Close();
    }

        protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            refreshdata();
        }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error about a reader already having an open connection? You don't need a reader and also an adapter. Use one or the other.

Comment: i think thats the problem i get this error : There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command, which must be closed first. but what do i do to fix it?

Comment: @Crowcoder i changed the code but it gives me the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readers and adapters are two mechanisms to execute queries. You should not use both. Even if there were no error you would be running a query twice for no reason. To use just an adapter remove all the reader stuff. An adapter will open and close the connection itself.

[And consider not using AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

```
protected void btnsearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [encomenda] where No_= @No_", con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_", txtSearch.Value);

    sqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda1.Fill(dt);
    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: its working, im very gratefull. instead of addwithvaule what should i use then?

Comment: The article I linked to explains it

Comment: use          cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@No_", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtSearch.Value;

Comment: of course, if No_ is a number, then use:                 cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@No_", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtSearch.Text"";  ----------- and I think you need .Text and not .Value ----- and note that .Add() is NOT deprecated unless you use it without .Value as I am.

Answer (score 0):

The only code on your `search button` should be like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select DISTINCT No_ from [encomenda] where No_= @No_", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@No_", txtSearch.Value);

SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
GridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

It is almost the same as how you load a data, the only difference is the query that you're passing on `SqlCommand`

*Also, you already using a `DataAdapter` on your code, so using `DataReader` is pretty useless.*

Comment: now i dont get the error anymore, but it doesnt change the gridview, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

I would consider one routine to load the grid, that way you only write that code one time.

So, your code can look like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack == false)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    public void LoadGrid()
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * from tblHotels ",
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            // now load grid
            if (txtCitySearch.Text != "")
            {
                cmdSQL.CommandText += "WHERE City = @City ";
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtCitySearch.Text;
            }
            cmdSQL.CommandText += "ORDER BY HotelName";
            MyGrid.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            MyGrid.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

So, if you have that search box, and a button to search again, then that looks like this:

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadGrid();
    }
```

So, you can well make the sql "optional" for the parameters as above shows.

Now, do note that I shove the reader results right into the grid. If you using the on data bound event, you MAY VERY WELL want to use/shove in a data table since often during data bind we want use of the full data row being used during the binding process.

eg this:

```
 // get City from current data row source - set the drop to data row City
 MyDrop.SelectedValue = ((DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem)["City"].ToString();
```

Now how we use the DataItem. The data item IS ONLY valid during the binding process, but as such, we often use it to get data/rows/information from the actually data source used during binding (say some PK value not displayed in the grid).

If you use:

```
MyGrid.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
```

Then you find dataitem is of the wrong data type. So, if you "going" to use DataItem and need full data row during the binding event, then as noted, use this:

```
DataTable rst = New Datatable();
rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
MyGrid.DataSource = rst;
```

That way then the data item is a correct data row of correct type that you can freely using during that binding process. Once the grid is loaded, then of course DataItem/Datasource is out of scope, and no longer exists.

But the full data row source during binding is available - but this then means you better off to use a datatable, and not send the "reader" results directly to the grid WHEN you need the full data row and all columns for your code during the binding process.